# Google Maps differencies from country

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

When trying to connect Google Maps using https://www.google.com.tr/maps zoom level is set to a level that view can not be understood.

When reaching same place on map from https://www.google.nl/maps zoom level is set to maximum.

Here is an example of zooming results:

[image]

Anybody know how to pass over this situation?

Here are links to check:

From Turkey servers: [40.742869, 30.330944](https://www.google.com.tr/maps/place/40%C2%B044'34.1%22N+30%C2%B019'51.4%22E/@40.7433231,30.3313585,252m/data=!3m1!1e3!4m5!3m4!1s0x0:0x0!8m2!3d40.742798!4d30.330933)

From Netherland servers: [40.742869, 30.330944](https://www.google.nl/maps/place/Turkije/@40.7430641,30.3317615,315m/data=!3m1!1e3!4m5!3m4!1s0x14b0155c964f2671:0x40d9dbd42a625f2a!8m2!3d38.963745!4d35.243322)

Comment: http://webrazzi.com/2016/07/11/google-mapste-turkiyenin-uydu-goruntuleri-neden-bulanik/ adding same sites tell about error

Comment: Here is no support proof from Google! Shame on you Google! https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/maps/Ixm4C6hviZQ

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing country from your own makes satellite maps clear.

[image: Changing own country setting link]

Click country name on bottom right of the page and then on setting page, select the closest country to your own region.

[image]